# Ajax loaded form elements not serialized

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, codeigniter-3

I'm wondering why the form elements which loaded via **ajax** inside a form weren't **posted(serialized)**. This is my code:

```
 <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal" onclick="load_credits_data('<?php echo $s['st_id'];?>','curriculum/home/get_student_memo','<?php echo $theYear;?>','<?php echo $theSeason;?>','<?php echo $s['semester_id'];?>','memo')" class="btn btn-xs green">
                      <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                    </a>
```

Form inside the modal:

```
<div id="editModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" data-width="400">
  <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
              aria-hidden="true"></button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">ملا حظات</h4>
  </div>
  <form method="post" class="form-horizontal" id="srs_memoFormID">
    <input type="hidden" name="test" id="test" value="2356789">
      <div id="memo">

      </div>
  </form>
```

Partial view which is loaded inside the form:

```
 <div class="modal-body" style="padding: 20px 30px;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <input type="hidden" name="student_srs_id" id="student_srs_id" value="<?php echo $srs_id; ?>">
          <label class="control-label">ملا حظات</label>
          <textarea name="srs_memo" id="srs_memo" form="srs_memoFormID" class="form-control">
              <?php echo $memo; ?>
          </textarea>
        </div>
      </div>         
    </div>
  <div class="modal-footer" style="padding: 0px 30px 30px;">
      <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default">بستن</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="update_st_memo('curriculum/home/update_memo','srs_memoFormID','memo')">ذخیره کردن </button>
  </div>
```

Ajax code:

```
function update_st_memo(target_controller, formID, target_tag) {
        $('#' + target_tag).css('height', 'auto').html('<img style="position: relative;top:40%;right:45%;" src="' + base_url + 'assets/css/loading-spinner-blue.gif"/>');
        // alert($('#test').val())
        $.ajax({
            url: base_url + target_controller,
            type: 'POST',
            // data: {srs_id: $('#srs_id').val(),memo: $('#memo').val()},
            data: $('#' + formID).serialize(),
            success: function (result) 
            {
              console.log(result)

            },
        })
    }
```

Comment: Show me your ajax code here

Comment: I've added ajax code at the bottom of the question @PankajMakwana

Comment: Are you getting any response to your ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Html Form:

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal" id="srs_memoFormID">
   <input type="hidden" name="test" id="test" value="2356789">
    <div id="memo">
    </div>
 </form>
```

In your script:

```
  data: $('#srs_memoFormID').serialize(),
   (OR)
  data: $('#srs_'formID).serialize(),
   (OR)
var dataString = $('#srs_memoFormID').serialize();
```

Comment: When I var_dump($this->input->post('student_srs_id')), just returns null @PankajMakwana ,@Karthik Saravanan    Note: the test input is posted which is already in the form tag.